# Gmail label/tag in sending

Tags: gmail

I am wondering if there is any functionality in Gmail so I can append label or tag to my email and then another Gmail recipient would receive this tags among the original message. This would be useful in project management with Gmail.

One solution would probably be to put label as string in Subject and then create filter on a recipients side. But this is not bulletproof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used hashtag as it is described in this page http://www.andreavascellari.com/?p=3758 and created filters. Until there is support for this feature also I guess this is the best way to manage this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No perhaps make a [feature request](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs) to the gmail team

Comment: I already did :) Hope my request will be processed at least :)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to achieve the same a few years ago and developed some functionalities to add these capabilities to my Gmail inbox. These features are now part of [Gmelius](https://gmelius.com).

To send and apply a label from a Gmail compose window, I use the "#" key and select the labels I want.

[image]

To ensure the label is automatically replicated with specific people, I create a [shared Gmail label](https://gmelius.com/shared-labels). These shared labels are automatically synchronized.

*[Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Gmelius]*